# Docsplit Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docsplit

I'm trying to get [docsplit](http://documentcloud.github.com/docsplit/) to work with my rails app.  Right now I'm just trying to get it to run locally.  I installed the gem and all of the dependencies.  All of the basic examples work in the command line and I was able to get the

```
Docsplit.extract_pdf('example.doc')
```

to work in my rails app.  However when I try to use extract_images, i.e.

```
Docsplit.extract_images('example.doc', :size => '1000x', :format => [:png, :jpg])
```

I get the following error:

```
Docsplit::ExtractionFailed (sh: pdfinfo: command not found):
  docsplit (0.6.1) lib/docsplit/info_extractor.rb:23:in `extract'
  (eval):3:in `extract_length'
  docsplit (0.6.1) lib/docsplit/image_extractor.rb:34:in `convert'
  docsplit (0.6.1) lib/docsplit/image_extractor.rb:19:in `extract'
  docsplit (0.6.1) lib/docsplit/image_extractor.rb:19:in `each'
  docsplit (0.6.1) lib/docsplit/image_extractor.rb:19:in `extract'
  docsplit (0.6.1) lib/docsplit/image_extractor.rb:18:in `each'
  docsplit (0.6.1) lib/docsplit/image_extractor.rb:18:in `each_with_index'
  docsplit (0.6.1) lib/docsplit/image_extractor.rb:18:in `extract'
  docsplit (0.6.1) lib/docsplit/image_extractor.rb:16:in `each'
  docsplit (0.6.1) lib/docsplit/image_extractor.rb:16:in `extract'
  docsplit (0.6.1) lib/docsplit.rb:58:in `extract_images'
  app/controllers/sandbox_controller.rb:53:in `split_doc'
```

I double checked and all of the dependencies are installed.  I'm guessing I missed something in the configuration in rails.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you don't skip the step of installing Poppler, as mentioned in the docs. http://poppler.freedesktop.org/ Install it with brew install poppler or whatever's appropriate in your preferred package manager. I had this same error. Installing Poppler fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem using FreeBSD. I solved it by installing [poppler-utils](http://www.freshports.org/graphics/poppler-utils/).

Comment: Thanks, running Centos on Amazon EC2 and this was it.

Comment: This also solved it for me running Amazon Linux 2014.03